# make copy of folder tree without files

Tags: powershell, copy, directory

I need to make copy of folder with subfolders, but do it without any files, except data that include folder "Project".

So I need to do new folders tree, but it should include only files that was present in subfolder named "Project".

ok, My solution:

```
$folder = dir D:\ -r
$folder

foreach ($f in $folder)
{
    switch ($f.name)
    {
    "project"
    {
        Copy-Item -i *.* $f.FullName D:\test2
    }

    default
    {
    Copy-Item  -exclude *.* $f.FullName D:\test2
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: you tried to do nothing and failed ?

Comment: I don't know how to stay files in "Project" folder.

Comment: dude, better read the faq section before you post: http://stackoverflow.com/faq - you should show what's the effort you took in order to solve your problem, show us the code that you tried writing and doesn't work, show us that you don't ask us to do your HW assignment...

Comment: ok I had put my code in topic. It's does not work respectively

Comment: An example of your folder structure would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
$source = "c:\dev"
$destination = "c:\temp\copydev"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
    ForEach-Object { $null = New-Item -ItemType Container -Path $_ -Force }

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object { -not $_.psIsContainer -and (Split-Path $_.PSParentPath -Leaf) -eq "Project"} |
    Copy-Item -Force -Destination { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `xcopy /t` to copy only the folder structure and then copy the `Project` folders separately. Something like this:

```
'test2\' | Out-File D:\exclude -Encoding ASCII
xcopy /t /exclude:d:\exclude D:\ D:\test2
gci -r -filter Project | ?{$_.PSIsContainer} | %{ copy -r $_.FullName d:\test2}
ri d:\exclude
```

Comment: I can't. There too many subfolders, and every of them are have "Project" folder.

Comment: If there are too many that any automated approach fails, then you have other problems already.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you mean by "and then copy the Project folders separately" manual copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to recurse over folders and remap structure using `New-Item`. Within recursion, you can easily check for "Project".

Answer (score 0):

First, create the directory structure:

```
xcopy D:\source D:\destination /t /e
```

Now, iterate through the source directory, copying every file in a Project directory:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Source * -Recurse |
    # filter out directories
    Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } |

    # grab files that are in Project directories
    Where-Object { (Split-Path -Leaf (Split-Path -Parent $_.FullName)) -eq 'Project' } | 

    # copy the files from source to destination
    Copy-Item -Destination ($_.FullName.Replace('D:\source', 'D:\destination'))
```